# C++: How to convert lowercase to upercase and viceversa with out ctype functions?

Tags: c++, string, ctype

```
int main(){
char text[500];
int j,h,op;
char b[]=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char a[]=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
cout<<"insert text:";fflush(stdin);gets(texto); 
        system("cls");
            cout<<"1-Minus to Mayus"<<endl;
            cout<<"2-Mayus to Minus"<<endl;
        cin>>op;
    system("cls");
    if (op==1)
                    {
                                j=0;
                                h=0;
                                while(j<28){

                                    if(text[h]==b[j]){
                                        text[h]=a[j];
                                        h++;
                                        j=0;
                                    }
                                    j++;
                                }
                                cout<<text<<endl;
                                system("pause");
                    }
                    else if (op==2)
                    {
                                j=0; 
                                h=0;
                                while(j<28){

                                    if(text[h]==a[j]){
                                        text[h]=b[j];
                                        h++;
                                        j=0;
                                    }
                                    j++;        
                                }
                                cout<<text<<endl;
                                system("pause");
                }
            }
```

**This code works just  with a single world (until the first space), I want it to run with a whole sentence or even a paragraph.I hope that you could understand the logic of lower to upper function in the main()**

Comment: Your code looks much to overcomplicated to achive this simple task. Just have a look here how the [ASCII character values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) correlate

Comment: Yeah, don't they teach about ASCII, in "Intro To Programming 101" any more?

Comment: @user0042 -- the problem statement isn't restricted to ASCII, so that may not be an option.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that. I'll bet a 100 quatloos the problem set is ASCII.

Comment: The first thing to do is to actually write a "lower to upper function" instead of stuffing all that code into `main`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `toupper` and `tolower`?  They were built to do this for you?

Comment: @pete Wouldn't there be a consistent correlation for e.g. the EBCDIC character sets as well? The distance value might be calculatable as `'A' - 'a'` for most character sets, no?

Comment: @user0042 -- maybe. The **only** guarantee you have about character conversions in C and C++ is that the characters `'0'` .. `'9'` are contiguous and increasing, so you can convert a value in the range 0..9 to the corresponding character by adding `'0'` to it. Other than that, you're making system-specific assumptions. That's why we have `tolower` and `toupper` -- to push the system-specific parts of the code off into the standard library so programs don't have to deal with them. I **really** don't understand this fascination with hacking ASCII when there are builtin functions that just work.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the case that you do not want this code to depend on the values of an ASCII table (although this could make your life much easier), following the spirit of your interestingly fashioned code, a function to convert letters to lowercase could be implemented as such:

```
const char LOWERCASES[] = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char CAPITALS[] = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

void toLowerCase(string &s) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned int l = 0; l < 27; ++i) {
            if (s[i] == CAPITALS[l]) {
                s[i] = LOWERCASES[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes, instead of ASCII, this would use what the compiler is told to put out via `-execution-charset` aka `-fexec-charset`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int main(){

int ss,T;

char text[100]; 

cout<<"Insert text ";gets(text);
T=tam(texto);
    cout<<"1)Menu "<<endl;
    cout<<"2)Upercase "<<endl;
    cout<<"3)LowerCase "<<endl;
    cout<<"4)Random"<<endl;cin>>ss;

switch(ss){

    case 2:
            for(int i=0 ; i<T ; i++){
                if(text[i]>=97 && text[i]<=122)
                    text[i]=int(text[i])-32;
            }
            cout<<text<<endl;

    break;  

    case 3:
            for(int i=0 ; i<T ; i++){
                if(text[i]>=65 && text[i]<=90)
                    text[i]=int(text[i])+32;
            }
            cout<<text<<endl;

    break;


    case 4:
            for(int i=0 ; i<T ; i++){
                if(text[i]>=97 && text[i]<=122)
                    text[i]=int(text[i])-32;
                else
                    text[i]=int(text[i])+32;    
            }

            cout<<text<<endl;

    break;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `tam()` ?